# How to build pytorch source?

Tags: pytorch

When I use pytorch, it showed that my the cuda version pytorch used and cuda version of system are inconsistent, so I need rebuild pytorch from source.

```sh
# install dependency
pip install astunparse numpy ninja pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing_extensions future six requests dataclasses

# Download pytorch source
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
# if you are updating an existing checkout
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --jobs 0

# Build
#if you want to use pytorch with cuda ,please `USE_CUDA=1`
python setup.py install

#torchvision install with source
# Download
git clone --recursive --branch v0.11.1 https://github.com/pytorch/vision.git

cd vision
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like the question contains both the question and answer part. Consider cleaning by putting the question into the question, then posting the answer as an answer and optionally accepting your own answer. It is ok to do this on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Building pytorch from source is not trivial, there is extensive documentation for it here[enter link description here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source) .
However I think you should try to either install directly a an older pytorch version compatible with your system version of cuda or use docker with the version (safer option).

You could also try to update your CUDA system if it supports newer drivers, good luck.